# cleanup after completion of a .NET Task

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have the following code that processes an INotification (custom interface)

```
var mgr = new NotificationManager();
var task = new Task(() => mgr.Send(notification));
task.Start();
```

Problem is once the Task completes, I need to perform some cleanup on notification.  What is the approach for doing this with the Task Parallel library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `ContinueWith`. Here is the documentation [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx)

Comment: Both answers are correct, but I like the ContinueWith option better.

Comment: They differ in whether the cleanup is called if Send throws. Since you said it's cleanup, always running is likely your goal, so ContinueWith is better. You can have ContinueWith filtered to just success/failure/cancel too

Comment: @John: Note that plain old `.ContinueWith()` will both have additional overhead of scheduling and executing a separate task and will be run asynchronously and thus have a delay. If you still want to use `ContinueWith` to perform cleanup, you can call `.ContinueWith()` with the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` as the second parameter. This will reduce the overhead and will almost always execute synchronously. It still entails overhead though.

Comment: @JamesManning: You can filter success/failure in a multi-line lambda too using `try-catch`. Cancellation is irrelevant in this case since there's no cancellation token, but even if there was it's still just a `try-catch`. I only use `.ContinueWith()` when I have an externally provided `Task` object that I was to attach a continuation to, not when I'm creating my own task where I can easily just write the control flow that's needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a multi-statement lambda:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { mgr.Send(notification); Cleanup(); };
```